# Visibility of a method in JAVA

Tags: java, oop, visibility

I am blocking on this question : 
Is every instance of Y able to call the method aMethod() of every other instance of Y.
The answer I found is NO.

```
    package a; 
    class X{ 
    protected void aMethod()
    { } 
    } 

    package b; 
class Y extends X
    { }
```

Can you explain to me why?
thanks.

Comment: See [Controlling Access to Members of a Class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html). The second table on that page explains your question. Where did you find that the answer is "no", and was there any explanation given?

Comment: @Jesper : in an online quizz, but there was no explanation, that's why I asked the question here..

Comment: @Jesper : is No the wrong answer?

Comment: @user199 , The answer is perfectly fine i.e. **NO** , reason is protected members can be accessed from the Subclasses in another package . but the Object of Y  can be created in other classes also that is why answer is fine .

Comment: Public variables – Visible to all classes.

Protected variables – Visible only to these classes which they belong, and any subclasses.

Friendly variables, the default – No modifiers are needed, Visible to the package.

Private variables – Visible only to the class to which they belong.

Comment: @Jesper: I didn't really get what you meant. I am getting confused. Can you please write a counter example as an answer and I'll accept it as the answer. thanks!